# Unity Genrics Animation controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, generics, animator

Hey guys working on a Genric Animation controller,

```
Public Animator anim

Public void GenAnim <t>(string "name", t val)
{
   If (t is float)
   {
       anim.setfloat ("name",  val)
   }

If (t is bool)
    {
     anim.settrigger("name",  val)
     }

If (t is int)
     {
     anim.setint ("name",  val)
     }
}
```

The issue was, you cant pass a t into anim.set functions and i couldn't work out how to cast it or get around it, i feel like there is an easy fix that I'm  missing
Please let me know if you have any ideas

Cheers

Comment: You could fix this by applying the casts you've just tested, i.e. in the `t is float` case you could write `anim.setfloat ("name",  (float) val);`. But this doesn't feel very OOP: the code shouldn't have to know the limited set of T that it can support and test for each. What are you trying to achieve? There must be a better way. Could you use overloaded functions maybe?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately the cast hasn't worked and i get "can not convert t to float, I need to display the use of generics for a job im applying for and This is something that I came up with opposed to the same gen list class thanks again

Comment: Oops, sorry: `Convert.ToSingle(val)` should work then (where 'single' is another name for 'float') since it has an overload that accepts object. But I don't think this is a good example for using generics if you want this as a portfolio-piece. Maybe get hold of some of the Unity example projects and see where they're using generics in an interesting way, or try and find a problem in one of them (or another sample you have of your own?) that you could solve with generics.

Comment: Thanks a million for the advice and suggestions Rup, I'll definitely have a look at some example projects cheers

Answer (score 2):

Generics can't really do this in a clean way, but @Rup's suggestion of method overloads would work:

```
public Animator anim;

public void SetParameter(string name, bool value)
{
    anim.SetBool(name, value);
}

public void SetParameter(string name, float value)
{
    anim.SetFloat(name, value);
}

public void SetParameter(string name, int value)
{
    anim.SetInteger(name, value);
}
```

That way calling SetParameter will choose the correct version based on the parameter you provide.

You could also have SetParameter(string name) without a value to call SetTrigger, but there is no GetTrigger (it's ResetTrigger instead). It's up to you how you want to handle that.